# Unable to create new function with Alibaba Cloud Function Compute Serverless Plugin

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework, alibaba-cloud, serverless-plugins, alibaba-cloud-function-compute

I am following this guide: [Aliyun Function Compute Serverless Plugin](https://github.com/aliyun/serverless-aliyun-function-compute) to try to create a new service with a new Node.js serverless function under the **Alibaba Cloud Function Compute** using the **Serverless Framework** as well as the **Aliyun Function Compute Serverless Plugin**.

However, after I have done with the `serverless deploy` command, I can only see a new service without any function created in the Alibaba Cloud Function Compute console, which is not what I expect.

I do not see any error during the deployment process.

Does anyone have any experience and solution on this?
Thanks very much!

The serverless.yml is as shown below:

```
service: aliyun-nodejs

    provider:
      name: aliyun
      runtime: nodejs8
      credentials: <private>

    plugins:
      - serverless-aliyun-function-compute
    package:
      exclude:
        - package-lock.json
        - .gitignore
        - .git/**

    functions:
      hello:
        handler: index.hello
        events:
          - http:
              path: /foo
              method: get
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `serverless config` before `serverless deploy` and see if that works? Under the issues section of Aliyun plugin's repo you can find this thread: 
https://github.com/aliyun/serverless-aliyun-function-compute/issues/3

Comment: It doesn't show anything after I run the serverless config command under the project's root